# Check In Check Out Work Items in TFS 2010 API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Does TFS 2010 have the concept of checking out work items and checking them in.  This action would lock the item for edit by other users while it is checked out.

I know I can do this for files under source control, but what about regular work items?

I haven't yet come across any documentation around this.  If it's possible, does someone have a code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. In TFS11 we have added 'merge on save' so there are less conflicts when saving a work item.

Would love to know why you want this feature though.

Comment: Writing an export tool for a 3rd party ALM system to send data to TFS.  We want to illiminate as many potential concurrency issues during the export as possible.  Perhaps, you can recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: Are you aware of the Integration Platform which is our recommended approach to integrate other systems to TFS? http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

Comment: We looked at it breifly, but didn't understand the benefit as the TFS API is well documented as is and allows us to manipulate everything we need in TFS with great simplicity.  What is the advantage here?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind.  I'd like to know why it's recommended over using the standard TFS API?

Comment: The integration platform is using the TFS API and is created to do migrations or synchronizations. When trying to synchronize data, there are a lot of issues that you need to take care of. The integration platform contains already all the plumbing you need to achieve this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sold as I just don't understand the value. It's not clear.  There is no documentation online about what this will actually do for us.  The TFS API is documented concretely enough that we've had no problems using the API to synchronize from a 3rd party system.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve a lock mechanism on work items if you write a custom control that allows or denies saving based on the result of some query you make to a custom service.

You would want to create a visual studio plugin that sets and resets the lock per work item.

While you're at it, you could write a server plugin that persists a serialized copy if the work item to disk or to the version control system.

I know it's a lot if work, but it should give you what you asked for.